# highcharts zoom bug (column chart)

Tags: javascript, highcharts, zooming

There's a zooming bug that we're struggling.

If you zoom in the left side of the chart, the right side of the chart is zoomed.

Simple example:
http://jsfiddle.net/andrut/TfG6c/

I do it like that:

```
   {
     "chart": {
         "renderTo": "container",
             "zoomType": "xy",
             "type": "column"
     },
     "plotOptions": {
         "series": {
             "groupPadding": 0.04
         }
     },
     "series": [{
         "name": "col0",
         "data": [{
             "y": 93723,
             "color": "#773676"
         }]
     }, {
         "name": "col1",
         "data": [{
             "y": 68630,
             "color": "#ff9900"
         }]
     }]
  }
```

Is there any workaround to fix this? I haven't found anything interesting anywhere...

Thanks,
Karol

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [minRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.minRange) paramter

```
yAxis:{
         minRange: 1000
     },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TfG6c/1/

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it doesn't help :( Still, when I try to zoom in on the left side, it zooms in on the right side...

Comment: You can set smaller minRange. I advice to use columns in one serie, not each serie for each point.